# IE6 fix for site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Here is the url to the site in question: http://www.katiesamsonlaxfest.com/index.html

The site looks fine in all the browsers except IE6 and below.  I would like if possible to find an easy css fix because as you can see the content is not contained within the divs.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just ignore the decade-old browser.

Comment: Start by validating it: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.katiesamsonlaxfest.com%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you're talking about, anyway. I actually see worse issues with IE7, since the content leaks out. For me in IE6 on Windows XP, the content looks just fine.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.katiesamsonlaxfest.com%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Ah, ok I just assumed this was I.E. 6, the problem must be 7 cause it works with 8

Comment: I'm not going to enter this is as a full answer, but I did notice you're using floats. That sort of leakage is what I usually see when inner elements are floated, but the outer element isn't properly clearfix'd. But your paragraphs in the content box aren't floated, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Might be a good question for doctype.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [YUI CSS Foundation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/#start) (Reset, Fonts, Grids). I find far less IE issues when building sites this way and often it requires almost no IE fixes/hacks once built and tested in Firefox.

It may take a little effort to learn, but I consider this to be the easiest fix because it almost eliminates the need for IE specific CSS and it saves you time in the long-run.

Comment: I agree, a CSS reset is always the best place to start. This won't fix your problem in itself, but at least you won't be fixing something on one browser while un-fixing it another.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "easy fix". You need to address the problems one at a time.

You can add "IE6"-specific CSS by adding things like:

```
.box {
    margin-left:20px;
    _margin-left:15px; /* this is the ie-specific fix */

}
```

...etc.

Also, transparency doesn't work with 24-bit PNG files. Use 8-bit. They're only titles, you don't need 24-bit anyways (or just use GIF). This is why your titles have strange boxes around them.